# not able to see the dot dot dot at the end of the line in the IE 11

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I have a requirement, I need to show in the jsp pargagraph as content. Now it is working fine in chrome. But the same code is not working in IE 11.
The problem is `...` missing in IE11.

Just see the output in chrome:

**sample 1-announcement with contentsample 1-announcement with...**

in IE 11

**sample 1-announcement with contentsample 1-announcement with content ldjflk**

for the above output I have used the following css :

```
.vp_announce_card_line_clamp {
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;  
  display: -ms-flexbox; 
}
```

Please tell me how can I resolve it in IE 11
or
Is there any alternative for this problem.

Comment: can you reproduce it in fiddle?

Comment: I think the word you're looking for is "ellipsis" :)